# ¿Como validar un arreglo sin acceder a sus propiedades?

Tags: php

Tengo un formulario extenso al cual envió por `post` al servidor (php), valido que si existe algo por `post` pues ejecute una acción, pero el problema que tengo o la duda que me genera es como validar si dentro de es `$_POST` existe un `name (de html)` vació, si tener que validar directamente ese `name ($_POST['name'], etc etc).`

**CODIGO**

```
    if(empty($_POST)){
        echo 'vacio';
        }else{
        echo 'lleno';
   }
```

lo intente asi y con un for pero tampoco me funciono.

Agradecería el interés.

Comment: Y como estas haciendo tu esa validación ahora, podrías poner como es que lo haces para darnos una idea. Saludos!

Comment: @SebastiánLagosYañez, claro que si, ya pongo lo que estoy realizando

Comment: envias un array o campo por campo?

Comment: serializo en el javascript y envio todo por ajax

Answer (score 1):

Espero entenderlo bien.

Mandas un form con muchos campos, a PHP le llega un array de este tipo

```
['input1' => valor1, 'input2' => valor2, 'input3' => valor3,...]
```

Lo que puedes hacer para verificar que no venga alguno vació es recorrerlos todos con un foreach() y declarar una variable que guarde un valor cuando se detecte que un campo viene vació, algo mas o menos así:

```
//$llave es el nombre asociativo del array
//$valor es lo que tiene asignado el array en $_POST[$llave]
//$bandera es nuestra variable de control
$bandera = TRUE;
foreach ($_POST as $llave => $valor) {
    //Detectamos si la variable esta vacía
    if(empty($_POST[$llave])){
        //El input quedo vació, se cambia el valor de $bandera
        $bandera = FALSE;
    }
}

if($bandera){
//Todos los campos vienen llenos
}else{
//Hay campos vacios
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu interés, he intentado hacerlo con ambas respuestas y me ha sido muy útil.

Answer (score 1):

Dado que no quieres acceder "directamente" a cada elemento del array para ver si esta vacio o no, una forma que puedes utilizar es con el uso de `array_filter` y `array_diff`.

Suponiendo el array $all (que seria tu $_POST, pero lo uso para ejemplo), puedes hacer:

```
$all = [
   'key1' => "hello",
   'key2' => "bye",
   'key3' => null,
   'key4' => "",
   'key5' => 0,
];

$noEmpty = array_filter($all);

$empty = array_diff($all, $noEmpty);


print_r($all);
print_r($noEmpty);
print_r($empty);
```

cuando ejecutamos array_filter($all), nos devuelve un array en el que solo estan los elementos cuyo valor no es vacio. En este caso, serian `key1` y `key2`.

ahora tenemos dos arrays: uno con todos los datos y otro con los que NO son nulos. Podemos utilizar `array_diff` para ver la diferencia entre `todos` y los `no nulos`. Esto es, aquellos que tienen valor vacio.

nota: se considera vacio aquellos valores que son `NULL`, cadena vacia o `0`. Esto es muy importante que lo tengas en cuenta.

Los resultados de los print_r serian:

```
Array
(
    [key1] => hello
    [key2] => bye
    [key3] => 
    [key4] => 
    [key5] => 0
)
Array
(
    [key1] => hello
    [key2] => bye
)
Array
(
    [key3] => 
    [key4] => 
    [key5] => 0
)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu interes. la verdad eres muy clara  tu respuesta.